# MoveTowards to original position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to save the initial position of the `cursor` at start, and after the `cursor` has been moved and the mouse button is released, it should return to its original position (using `10f * Time.deltaTime`), but this does not work

```
[SerializeField] private Transform cursor;
private Vector3 OriginalPosition;

void Start()
{
    OriginalPosition = cursor.transform.position;
    Debug.Log(OriginalPosition);
}

void OnMouseUp()
{
    Debug.Log("MouseUp");
    cursor.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(cursor.position, OriginalPosition, 10f * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: Are you using a virtual cursor? if not, could I assume that the cursor is just a game object and has no relation to your mouse cursor?

Comment: @Nefisto Yes, the cursor is just a game object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are assuming that calling a MoveForward will make your game object follow all its way back to the original position, which will not happen, what you're actually doing is saying to your cursor "when I release my mouse button, calculate the direction between my current position and original position and with a speed of 10 units per second move the amount that it would be in 1 frame". What you need is to make the MoveToward operation during the period of N frames, for making this happen you need to use a coroutine, so follow a similar code

```
public Transform cursor;
public Transform originalPosition;

public void Move()
{
    StartCoroutine(MoveToTargetPosition());
    
    IEnumerator MoveToTargetPosition()
    {
        while (Vector3.Distance(cursor.position, originalPosition.position) >= .5f)
        {
            yield return null;

            cursor.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(cursor.position, originalPosition.position, 10f * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Change `OriginalPosition.position` to `OriginalPosition`, otherwise it gives an error